# How to display data from two tables in sequence alternately

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select data alternately from two tables and create a new column which is `address_type` to describe the contents of the address. First table is `Postal_Address`:

```
ID   Name    Postal_Address
-------------------------------
123  Alex    Decker Hill A
343  Flynn   Apartment A
```

Second table is `Electronic_address`

```
ID   Name   Phone_type   Phone_Number
----------------------------------------
123  Alex    Mobile      99776
123  Alex    Mobile      99876
343  Flynn   Mobile      98798
```

The result I am trying to get is:

```
ID   Name    Address_type  Phone_Type  Phone_Number  Postal_Address
--------------------------------------------------------------------
123  Alex    1              Mobile     99776 
123  Alex    1              Mobile     99876 
123  Alex    2                                       Decker Hill A
343  Flynn   1              Mobile     98798                    
343  Flynn   2                                       Apartment A
```

I had tried case, but still don't get this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the 'address type' flag as part of a query against each table, then union queries against both tables, and order the result by ID and that flag:

```
select id, name, 1 as address_type, phone_type, phone_number, null as postal_address
from electronic_address
union all
select id, name, 2, null, null, postal_address
from postal_address
order by id, address_type;

        ID NAME  ADDRESS_TYPE PHONE_ PHONE_NUMBER POSTAL_ADDRES
---------- ----- ------------ ------ ------------ -------------
       123 Alex             1 Mobile        99776              
       123 Alex             1 Mobile        99876              
       123 Alex             2                     Decker Hill A
       343 Flynn            1 Mobile        98798              
       343 Flynn            2                     Apartment A
```

You could also combine the data into fewer rows:

```
select coalesce(e.id, p.id) as id,
  coalesce(e.name, p.name) as name,
  e.phone_type,
  e.phone_number,
  p.postal_address
from electronic_address e
full outer join postal_address p on p.id = e.id
order by id;

        ID NAME  PHONE_ PHONE_NUMBER POSTAL_ADDRES
---------- ----- ------ ------------ -------------
       123 Alex  Mobile        99776 Decker Hill A
       123 Alex  Mobile        99876 Decker Hill A
       343 Flynn Mobile        98798 Apartment A
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3770f4f6e4f3f38df95df035888d5090)

You should probably have a third table with ID and name, and then have the two tables you've shown linked to that via just the ID (so they don't duplicate the name), with a primary/foreign key relationship; something more like [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=beab224504d6ca27815227b00aec6dbd).